# How do I set up sequelizejs to use a version column?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

How do I set up Sequelize to use an auto increment version number?

According to the documentation, all I need is just setting version: true: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#configuration

**First attempt:**

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";

export const sequelize = new Sequelize('my_connection', 'fake-user-name', 'fake-password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'postgres'
});

export const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  id: {type: Sequelize.STRING, primaryKey: true},
  name: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false}
}, {
  underscored: true,
  tableName: 'r_users',
  version: true // <- here
});
```

Result: there is no version column created.

**Second attempt:**

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";

export const sequelize = new Sequelize('my_connection', 'fake-user-name', 'fake-password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'postgres'
});

export const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  id: {type: Sequelize.STRING, primaryKey: true},
  name: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false},
  version: {  // <- here as well
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: 0
  }
}, {
  underscored: true,
  tableName: 'r_users',
  version: true
});
```

Result: version column is created, but it doesn't auto increment when updating the record (I expect the below would increment version):

```
User.find({where: {id: 1}}).then(item => {
  item.name = "Bob";
  item.save();
});
```

**Notes:**

I'm using postgres 9.6 and the libraries I'm using are as below:

- "sequelize": "^3.30.4"
- "pg": "^6.2.3",
- "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",

**Question:**

Could anyone help me to point out what I have done wrong?

Thanks in advance.